# How to trim JSON Object removing whitespace

Tags: javascript, jquery, json

I hava a common ajax.post method which accepts data from function parameter. Now i want to trim the properties of data. Below is the code.

```
function PostToServer(options) {
    var defaults = {
        'url': null,
        'data': null,
        'onSuccess': null,
        'onError': null
    };
    var parameters = $.extend(defaults, options);
    $.ajax({
        url: parameters.url,
        type: "POST",
        data: JSON.stringify(parameters.data),
        contentType: "application/json",
        success: function (res) {
            if ($.isFunction(parameters.onSuccess)) {
                parameters.onSuccess(res);
            }
        },
        error: function (xhr, status, error) {
            if ($.isFunction(parameters.onError)) {
                parameters.onError(xhr, status, error);
            }
        }
    });
}
```

Now in this function i want to trim the 'parameters.data' object so that it removes whitespace from both ends. but i dont know what comes in 'parameters.data' so i can not access its properties and use trim function.
Please help.

Comment: you want to iterate and trim each property in the `parameters.data` object?

Comment: I think the easiest solution is to iterate through every property then trim and add it to a FormData Object: [MDN Formdata](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/Guide/Using_FormData_Objects?redirectlocale=en-US&redirectslug=Web%2FAPI%2FFormData%2FUsing_FormData_Objects)

Comment: can you please provide code?

Comment: Because i dont know what comes in data and what will be its property name hence i can not trim its property using property name, i need some generalized way to trim.

Comment: before the ajax request try `$.each(parameters.data, function(key, val){
    data[key] = $.trim(val)
})`

Answer (score 1):

Try this:

```
$.each(res, function(index) {
    var that = this;
    $.each(that, function(key, value) {
        var newKey = $.trim(key);

        if (typeof value === 'string')
        {
            that[newKey] = $.trim(value);
        }

        if (newKey !== key) {
            delete that[key];
        }
    });
});
```

Comment: using your code and above suggestions i came up with this code and it works for me.

`function TrimData(data) {
        $.each(data, function (key, val) {
            if (typeof (val) == "object") {
                TrimData(val);
            }
            else {
                data[key] = $.trim(val)
            }
        });
        return data;
    }`